# Angular Looping through an array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, object, ngfor

I have an array which appears as follows:

```
[
 {
  myTitle:"myTitle",
  myDate:"myDate",
  images: [
   { imageDate:"date", imagePath:"path"}
  ]
 }
]
```

In my HTML, i loop over the array:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div> {{ item.myTitle }}
</li>
```

What I'd like to do is pull a value for the images also. Something like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div> {{ item.myTitle }}
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let image of item">
       {{ image.imagePath }}
     </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Is it possible to loop through the images array and reference a specific value?

Comment: `*ngFor="let image of item.images"`

Comment: I am a react guy, so I am not sure if this is the correct syntax, but  <li *ngFor="let image of item.images"> should work

Comment: Thank you both for the responses guys. They were also correct.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div> {{ item.myTitle }} </div>
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let image of item.images">
       {{ image.imagePath }}
     </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Damn, slightly embarrassing. So close. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fg9qdy?file=src/app/app.component.html)

.ts

```
 items=[
 {
  myTitle:"myTitle one",
  myDate:"myDate",
  images: [
   { imageDate:"date", imagePath:"path"}
  ]
 },
 {
  myTitle:"myTitle two",
  myDate:"myDate",
  images: [
   { imageDate:"date", imagePath:"path"}
  ]
 },
 {
  myTitle:"myTitle three",
  myDate:"myDate",
  images: [
   { imageDate:"date", imagePath:"path"}
  ]
 }
]
```

.html

```
<ul >
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span class="badge">{{ item.myTitle }}</span> 
     <div *ngFor="let image of item.images">
       {{ image.imagePath }}
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```